# Strange behaviour involving `display` property

Tags: string, text-properties, equality

I noticed a rather peculiar behavior when using the `display` property (using emacs 28.2). I tried to boil things down to a minimal example: The code

```lisp
  (defun finsert ()
    (insert (propertize "." 'display "|")))

  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "test"))

  ;; (finsert)
  (insert (propertize "." 'display "|"))
  
  (insert "1")
  (finsert)
  (insert "2")

  (goto-char 2)
  (delete-char 1)
```

inserts some propertized text into a new buffer `test` and removes one char. Then the new buffer shows `||2` (with each `|` using the `display` property).

I replaced `(insert (propertize "." 'display "|"))` with `(finsert)` (which I assumed would give the same result):

```lisp
  (defun finsert ()
    (insert (propertize "." 'display "|")))

  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "test"))

  (finsert)
  ;; (insert (propertize "." 'display "|"))
  
  (insert "1")
  (finsert)
  (insert "2")

  (goto-char 2)
  (delete-char 1)
```

But that shows only `|2`  (previously it showed `||2`). Moreover, the `2` will be at position `3` (not `2`) and both `|` seemed to got kind of merged...

Why is that happening? And why are both code snippets not producing the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is exactly answered by the doc in (elisp) [Replacing Specs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Specs.html).

Consecutive text with the same `display` property is handled as a block, replacing it by the `display` property.

> If a list of display specifications includes **more than one replacing
> display specification, the first overrides the rest**.  Replacing display
> specifications make most other display specifications irrelevant, since
> those don’t apply to the replacement.

But what matters is what "the same" means. Here it means `eq`, which for a string, such as `"|"`, means it has to be the same string object, not just two different string objects that have the same sequence of chars.

> For replacing display specifications, “the text that has the
> property” means all the consecutive characters that have the **same Lisp
> object** as their ‘display’ property; these characters are replaced as a
> single unit.  If two characters have different Lisp objects as their
> ‘display’ properties (i.e., **objects which are not ‘eq’**), they are
> handled separately.

In your first example you propertize the string `"."` with a string `"|"`, and you insert that. Then you do the same thing with **another** string `"|"`. Two different strings, even though they're applied to consecutive chars, means two separate `display` properties.

In your second example, you use function `finsert` to insert the same propertized string multiple times.

This is a bit like the problem of using `'(some list)` in a `let` binding and then modifying that list. The source code `"."` puts that single string into the function definition.  This is different from having Lisp read and eval separate `propertize` calls, reading separate strings that each look like `"|"`.

Please read all of the cited node of the manual. It shows a clear example that corresponds exactly to what you do and see. The example puts two different (non-`eq`) strings with the same replacement text on consecutive text, with two uses of property `display`.

All of the chars that get each of the properties are handled as a block/unit. But the two uses of `display`, with two different strings, mean that there are two such blocks of consecutive text, each with a different string used for property `display`. The two strings are `equal` (`string=`), but they are not `eq`: they are not the same string object.

If you don't want the same string (`eq`) to be used every time you call `finsert`, then tell it to create a new string each time, using `make-string`:

```lisp
(defun finsert ()
  (insert (propertize "." 'display (make-string 1 ?|))))
```

Then you'll always see `||2`, because a different string `"|"` will be used each time `finsert` is called.

Comment: Wow, I am very impressed!!!  I was already assuming a kind of bug... But now this makes total sense! Thank you very much!!!